# google-chart linear regression with month on the x-axis

Tags: google-visualization, linear-regression

I have this scatter plot:

[image]

It's month-number. If I convert month to a number (1-12), I can calculate regression line like this:

[image]

Is there anyway to keep the month, not having to convert to number and still run linear regression?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try leaving your scatter plot with the numbers for the x-axis, but customizing your tick labels to show months.

Add this to your `options` object.

```
hAxis:{ticks:[{v:1,f:'Jan'},{v:2,f:'Feb'},{v:3,f:'Mar'},{v:4,f:'Apr'},         
              {v:5,f:'May'},{v:6,f:'Jun'},{v:7,f:'Jul'},{v:8,f:'Aug'},
              {v:9,f:'Sep'},{v:10,f:'Oct'},{v:11,f:'Nov'},{v:12,f:'Dec'}]}
```